Would this sentence use A or AN before NIA?
This sentence was published in The Hindu It goes like this -

The L-G had on Monday
recommended a NIA probe into allegations of the SFJ funding AAP based on a complaint by an outfit named World Hindu Federation- India.**  (source)

I believe AN should be used before the term NIA probe instead of A.
Help me out here...

Please link to the source in the "reputed newspaper".  When citing a source you must give enough details for someone to check it themselves.  The easiest way is a URL, but if that's not possible the name, date and page in the newspaper would be sufficient.

I've done this for you, to show how it can be done.

It depends on how the abbreviation is pronounced.
If you say "en-eye-ay" then "an NIA"
If you say "NIA" like "near" then "a NIA"
The change from a to an is not a grammar rule, it is a sandhi rule, and depends completely on pronunciation.

I must admit I am 72, studied English to degree level, and have never heard of a 'sandhi rule'. Where does it come from?

I must admit I am 64, studied linguistics as a minor, and have never heard of a ‘sandhi rule.’  Turns out, @MichaelHarvey, it comes from Sanskrit.

placing sandhi rules in opposition to grammar rules seems somewhat artificial to me. Especially as this sandhi rule only applies to the indefinite article, and not to other phonetically identical material so is not purely phonological, but has to be sensitive to aspects of the grammar

It is the change in pronunciation of a word (or part of a word) due the phonetic environment it is in.  Many changes are only noted in speech and not in writing, for example the pronunciation of the past tense ending "ed" can be  "id"  (in fasted) or "d"  (in played) or "t" (in passed)  it is orthogonal to grammar rules, which depend on the grammatical environment (such as whether a word is a subject or object).  "N.I.A and "Nia" would have the same grammatical class, but are phonetically different.

@JamesK thank you so much for your helpful response. I did not know about adding the source link. :)

Just to make things explicit: There isn't a right answer. Since only some readers will read an initialism without expanding it, neither choice can satisfy all readers.

There may be a consensus.  "SUV" is never "suv"  And  "NASA" is never "en-ay-es-ay".  So always "an SUV" but "A NASA rocket"

There are words like “heir” that some people speak with a silent h, and others with a sounding h. So you may read “an heir” or “a heir”. If you read it out loud, you read the first with a silent h, and the second with a sounding h.

@gnasher729  "heir" is always silent "h" (in all standard dialects).  [Eliza Doolitle might say "it 'ardly hever 'appens"  but that's non-standard]
